# Tips to Improve the Web Page Performance in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, performance, stored-procedures

I have a website with multiple webpages.Among that one page is having 3 gridviews,20 dropdownlists and some ajax javacript calls. i am calling 15 stored procedures to fill the in gridviews and dropdownlists.

Since so many controls and stored procedure calls within the page, loading itself taking too much time.How can i improve the performance.I can't remove the existing gridviews and dropdownlists.

Any one please suggest the tips to improve my page response speed..

Comment: What kind of profiling have you done? But in the end, if the page has to do a lot of things, and some of those things take time then the page will not be fast.

Comment: read more about Page perfomance  ..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx  another http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/263166/How-Improve-ASP-net-performence

Comment: @ Richard: What you mean by profiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three options:

1. Minimize the stored procedure calls at the time of page load. You can do it, let's say out of those 20 dropdowns 12 are dependent on the other 8. Bind them on the `change` event of those 8.
2. You can put some button to show the 2nd and 3rd if possible to reduce two more database calls.
3. You can combine some of the stored procedure in one and pull multiple tables in one dataset and use it to populate few of the dropdowns.